# Google Mock for nullptr testing

Tags: c++, testing, mocking, assertions, googlemock

I am going to test this part of code using GMock. I want to check that `start` method does not execute when `BPtr` is null.

How can I check this kind of scenario?

```
 currentPtr=APtr;

         if(nullptr != APtr->BPtr)
          {
            object.start(currentPtr);
          }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I've suggested an edit to your question to make it less about opinions, more about solutions. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) gives guidelines about subjective questions.

Comment: Some opinions: 1) The condition tests `APtr` but then the body uses `currentPtr`. This is generally confusing. Test `currentPtr->BPtr`. 2) I prefer the thing you test first and the literal you test against last, so `i == 2` or `currentPtr->BPtr != nullptr` in your case. 3) Many people just write `if (currentPtr->BPtr)` but I like to check against nullptr explicitly. But That's just my opinion and not an answer.